# Intersection of two uniformities is not a uniformity. Counterexample in Willard, repeated in a previous post. Here is my counter-counterexample.

Tags: general-topology

Here is the link to another answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/295936/560510

I am confused. Here is my attempt to construct a counterexample to the counterexample in the referenced post.

Suppose we consider: $$ \mathscr{D}_{12} = \{D \subseteq X \times X : \Delta \cup\{(1,a),(1,b),(a,1),(b,1),(a,b),(b,a)\} \subseteq D \} $$

Is this collection not contained in $ \mathscr{D}_1 $ and $ \mathscr{D}_2 $ and therefore their intersection? It appears to not have the defect suggested in the previous answer. In particular, the set

$$  \mathscr{A}_0 = \Delta \cup\{(1,a),(1,b),(a,1),(b,1),(a,b),(b,a)\} $$

is closed under composition unlike the set so named in the previous answer.

I am sorry I am missing something. This example is from Willard, Problem 35E, but I don't understand why my proposed solution fails. The purported counter-example (as also given in Willard) defines the uniformities $ \mathscr{D}_1 $ and $ \mathscr{D}_2 $ to be **all** subsets of $ \mathbf{I} \times  \mathbf{I} $ **containing** $ \Delta \cup\{(1,a),(a,1)\} $ and $ \Delta \cup\{(1,b),(b,1)\} $, respectively.

I suspect that the symmetry requirement is somehow violated but I don't see how the wording in the problem prevents such spoilage.

Comment: The problem is that $\mathscr{D}_{12}$ is not the whole of the intersection; it is a proper subset of the intersection. The claim is not that there is no uniformity *contained* in $\mathscr{D}_1\cap\mathscr{D}_2$, the claim is that the intersection $\mathscr{D}_1\cap\mathscr{D}_2$ is not a uniformity. The set $\Delta\cup\{(1,a),(a,1),(1,b),(b,1)\}$ lies in $\mathscr{D}_1\cap\mathscr{D}_2$, but not in $\mathscr{D}_{12}$, so $\mathscr{D}_{12}\subsetneq \mathscr{D}_1\cap\mathscr{D}_2$.

Comment: Many thanks for that clarification. So, the set $  \mathscr{A}_0 = \mathscr{A}_0 = \Delta \cup\{(1,a),(1,b),(a,1),(b,1)\} $ lies in the intersection.

Comment: Yes, because it lies in $\mathscr{D}_1$ and also in $\mathscr{D}_2$.

Comment: So, the set $  \mathscr{A}_0 = \Delta \cup\{(1,a),(1,b),(a,1),(b,1)\} $ lies in the intersection. If the intersection was a uniformity, that forces $$ \mathscr{A}_0 \circ \mathscr{A}_0 $$ to be in the intersection. But I think it is, as an overset of $ \mathscr{A}_0 $ that is already contained in both.

Comment: If the intersection were a uniformity, this would for *some set* $V$ in the intersection to satisfy $V\circ V\subseteq \mathscr{A}_0$. But for every set $V$ in the intersection you have $(a,b)\in V\circ V$; since $(a,b)\notin \mathscr{A}_0$, for every $V\in\mathscr{D}_{1}\cap\mathscr{D}_2$ you have $V\circ V\not\subseteq \mathscr{A}_0$.

Comment: I understand your point sir. I am having trouble with the semantics. Thank you very much. I have better understanding now. I had already found the issue, but rejected it using wrong intuition.

Comment: (Also note that what you know is that every overset of something in a uniformity is in the uniformity; you seem to be trying to argue the converse, that if an overset is in the uniformity then the set is in the uniformity, and that is false...)

Comment: Exactly! A good lesson for me here! Thank you again!